# this.getClass().getPackage() returns null in Tapestry?

Tags: java, class, maven, null, tapestry

I am using Tapestry 5.3 framework with Maven. 
I have this use case where I am adding some configurations based on the package. There I have the abstract BasePage, and other pages in various packages inheriting it.

```
public abstract class BaseTypePage {

    public String getPackage() {
        return this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
    }
}

public class Index extends BaseTypePage {}
```

And when I navigate to that Index page, I get NullPointerException where getPackage() returns null.

When simply move the method from abstract to Index page, then it works, but only after 2nd load.

I guess the case might be that ClassLoader didn't collect all information about given class. But how do I fix it?

Comment: I might comment on this that in pure Java project this works like a charm.

Comment: Is `Index` actually in a package?  `Class#getPackage()` returns null if the class is in the default package.